# \thanks with label while using hyperref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, titles

I want to use `\label` `\ref` pairs in the title material of the standard classes.
Hence I have extended the `\thanks` macro with an optionally provided label name e.g. `\thanks[label]{Thanks}`.
Then I can use `\ref` within the title material e.g. `\author{Author \ref{label}}`.
This fails when I load `hyperref`.
However, it still works if I use the `\thanks` macro after `\begin{document}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thefootnote{\textsuperscript{\@fnsymbol\c@footnote}} % just for the look
\DeclareRobustCommand\thanks[2][]{%
  \if\relax#1\relax% check if no optional argument
    \footnotemark% use normal thanks
  \else%
    \protect\refstepcounter{footnote}\protect\label{#1} % add footnote label
  \fi%
  \protected@xdef\@thanks{% copy paste from original code
    \@thanks\protect\footnotetext[\the\c@footnote]{#2}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref} % everything works without hyperref

\title{Title}
\author{Author\ref{a}} % should add a footnotemark

\thanks[a]{Thanks} % Footnote text works only outside the header if hyperref is loaded
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

How can I make the modified `\thanks` work in the header while using `hyperref`?

Comment: move the `\thanks[a]{Thanks}` behind \begin{document}.

Comment: of course that works, but I would like to keep all the title related stuff in the header. Do you know what `hyperref` is doing that has to happen after `\begin{document}`?

Comment: some of hyperref changes are done at begin document. Your label has the wrong format, when you write it in the preamble. Use `\AddToHook{begindocument/end}{\thanks...}` to move your \thanks behind the hyperref code

Comment: Indeed that works nicely. If you wrote it as an answer I would accept it. Otherwise I could write it also by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment from Ulrike Fischer I came up with following solution.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\thefootnote{\textsuperscript{\@fnsymbol\c@footnote}}
\let\old@thanks\thanks % save the normal thanks
\DeclareRobustCommand\thanks[2][]{% redefine thanks
  \AddToHook{begindocument/end}{% but postpone the change until it is needed
    \if\relax#1\relax%
      \footnotemark%
    \else%
      \protect\refstepcounter{footnote}\protect\label{#1}%
    \fi%
    \protected@xdef\@thanks{%
      \@thanks\protect\footnotetext[\the\c@footnote]{#2}%
    }%
  }%
}
\AddToHook{begindocument/begin}{\let\thanks\old@thanks} % present hyperref with the usual thanks
\let\old@maketitle\maketitle
\def\maketitle{\old@maketitle\def\thefootnote{\@arabic\c@footnote}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{Title \ref{t}}
\thanks[t]{Title thanks}
\author{Author\ref{a}}
\thanks[a]{Author thanks}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\footnote{Footnote}

\end{document}
```